# Input in a modal cause flickering only on the Phone

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-modal, forms

I have 2 inputs in a form inside a modal.

```
{!! Form::open(array('id'=>'guest_note')) !!}
{{-- Name --}}
<div class="col-xs-12 form-group float-label-control" style="display:block; text-align: center; ">
  <label for="">Name</label>
  <input id="name" style="width: 70%;" required type="text" class="normal pull-left" placeholder="Name" required>

  <div style="margin-left: 10px" id="lv-avatar" class="lv-avatar pull-right hidden"></div>
</div>

{{-- Message --}}
<div class="col-xs-12 form-group float-label-control">
 <label for="">Message</label>
 <textarea id="message" minlength=4 rows="5" type="text" class="normal" placeholder="Message to us " required ></textarea>
</div>

<div class="col-xs-12 send_note_div">
 <a name="send" ng-click="note()" class="button send_note" style="width: 100%;"> DONE

 <img src="/img/svg/default.svg" alt="Loading" style="width: 7%; float: right; padding-top: 7px; " class="hidden loading">

 </a>
</div>
{!! Form::close();!!}
```

---

## Result

For some reasons, in

**Desktop Mac OS X on Chrome**

It is working fine.

I've also try it on Chrome Device Toolbar

[image]

It's also seem working fine.

**iPhone/iPad on Safari/Chrome**

> It shows a glitch.

Since it hard to show using screenshot, I captured the video of that glitch here :
https://www.dropbox.com/s/s1b72tjj3zzxetk/Glitch%20in%20the%20modal.mov?dl=0

How can I prevent that ?

Comment: What you mean "desktop" and "phone" what browsers are using on both ? Safari ? Chrome ?

Comment: Desktop on a Mac, Windows, on Chrome is running fine.

Comment: iPhone/iPad on Safari giving me the glitch error ...

Comment: If you give me a codepen or jsbin that i could reproduce, i would look into it. Seems like a weird safari padding/margin bug when the keyboard appears. Have you tried on android phone ? Or can you give me a link to your website so i can live test?

Comment: Please kindly go to my wedding site, on your phone here : http://www.bunlongheng.com/wedding

Comment: Works fine on chrome for android on my nexus 5.

Comment: Aww man :(.. Do you think this is a Safari on Mobile isssue ?

Comment: Looks like it..

Comment: I can't reproduce it either... But looking at your video, it looks like on `input`-`focus`, the menu retracts. If you could detect device on `load`, you could hide the menu on modal open. And set the modal top position to viewport top before an `input`-`focus` occurs. So, can't help more than just saying this.

Comment: Thanks - I will add your suggestions to my list of tries. :D

Comment: I just tried it on Samsung Galaxy S3 (with Chrome for Android)... And same comments! But the menu doen't hide, and it should. Just bring it back on modal close. ;)

Comment: Ok. Good reservation, I'll look into the play button on that menu. Maybe it prevent the nav to be hidden when it should. I'm just guessing here.

Comment: I guess, I will just follow your suggestion. Thank-you so much both of you for your time and helps :)